# select statement to return additional row

Tags: sql-server

I am  creating reports in SSIS using datasets and have the following SQL requirement:

The sql is returning three rows:

```
a
b
c
```

Is there anyway I can have the SQL return an additioanal row without adding data to the table?

Thanks in advance,
Bruce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select MyCol from MyTable
union all
select 'something' as MyCol
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNION ALL` to include a new row.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'newRow'
```

The number of columns needs to be the same between the top query and the bottom one.  So if you first query has one column, then the second would also need one column.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add multiple values there is a stranger syntax available:

```
declare @Footy as VarChar(16) = 'soccer'
select 'a' as Thing, 42 as Thingosity -- Your original SELECT goes here.
  union all
  select *
    from ( values ( 'b', 2 ), ( 'c', 3 ), ( @Footy, Len( @Footy ) ) ) as Placeholder ( Thing, Thingosity )
```